# How to sort a nested object map and assign value based on sorted efficiently?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have an object like:

```
{
  "playerId1": {
    "score": 100,
    "rank": 0
  },
  "playerId2": {
    "score": 500,
    "rank": 0
  },
  "playerId3": {
    "score": 200,
    "rank": 0
  }
}
```

and I need to sort them based on score then assign the sorted order to rank.
What would be the best approach?

I have tired converting to Array then sorting is easy, but I want to keep the Object structure.

Comment: Objects do not have any guarantee as to what order their keys will be in.  If you want elements to have an order, use an array.

Comment: Though, nothing about setting the rank says you have to "keep" the array.  You can utilize the array to set the rank and discard it after the fact.

Comment: That's not how object properties work. If you want to keep the object then create an array, sort, and gather the object property names for later use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the rank and keep it as an object.

```js
var temp = {
  "playerId1": {
    "score": 100,
    "rank": 0
  },
  "playerId2": {
    "score": 500,
    "rank": 0
  },
  "playerId3": {
    "score": 200,
    "rank": 0
  }
};

Object.values(temp).sort(function(a, b){
  return a.score - b.score;
}).forEach(function(player, rank){
  player.rank = rank;
});

console.log(temp);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using some sorting, mapping and reducing you can deconstruct and then reconstruct the object.

```js
const obj = {
  "playerId1": {
    "score": 100,
    "rank": 0
  },
  "playerId2": {
    "score": 500,
    "rank": 0
  },
  "playerId3": {
    "score": 200,
    "rank": 0
  }
}

let r = Object.keys(obj)
  .reduce((result, key) => {
    let v = obj[key]
    v['p'] = key
    return result.concat(v)
  }, [])
  .sort((a, b) => b.score - a.score)
  .map((itm, idx) => {itm.rank = idx + 1; return itm})
  .reduce((result, itm) => {result[itm['p']] = itm; delete result[itm['p']]['p']; return result}, {})

console.log(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't sort the object. But you can keep the object as it is an pull a sorted array in a bunch of different ways. For example if you just want a sorted list of players by rank you can:

```js
let obj = {"playerId1": {"score": 100,"rank": 0},"playerId2": {"score": 500,"rank": 3},"playerId3": {"score": 200,"rank": 2}}

let sortedPlayers = Object.keys(obj).sort((a, b) => obj[a].rank - obj[b].rank)
console.log(sortedPlayers)
```

Or you could create an array with players and scores that's sorted:

```js
let obj = {"playerId1": {"score": 100,"rank": 0},"playerId2": {"score": 500,"rank": 3},"playerId3": {"score": 200,"rank": 2}}

let sortedPlayers = Object.entries(obj).sort(([k1, v1], [k2, v2]) => v1.rank - v2.rank).map(([player, scores]) => ({player, scores}))
console.log(sortedPlayers)
```

It all depends on what you need to do and the specific output you want.